# How can I display a number in time format using Autoform?

Tags: meteor, time, meteor-autoform

I am currently making a form in Meteor using Autoform and trying to get the user to input the time limit they want to use for an event. My current schema looks like the example below but I am just wondering how to change the timeLimit object so that instead of just displaying a number in the format '0', it will return in the format '00:00' and give me the ability to log the info in seconds.

```
EventSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Event Name"
  },
  timeLimit: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Time Limit"
  },
  rounds: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Rounds"
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want a text field where they are able to type a number of seconds? Do they need to also be able to type in the format '00:00'? Or do you want them to type one and have it convert to the other?

Comment: @AutumnLeonard Sorry I guess I wasn't specific enough. They would need to be able to either type in the format '00:00' or push the plus/minus button on the side to make the number of minutes go up/down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to have one field for user entry, which would be a string in the "mm:ss" format.  And another field that is computed and displays the number of seconds.

So in this example, you'd show the timeLimitString field on forms, so the user could enter in "mm:ss" format.  And use the autoValue function on the timeLimit field to calculate the number of seconds (this example uses moment.js library to calculate seconds);

```
EventSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Event Name"
  },
  timeLimitString: {
    type: String,
    regEx: // define regex here for "mm:ss" format
  },
  timeLimit: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Time Limit",
    autoValue: function() {
       var string = this.field("timeLimitString");
       if (string.isSet) {
           var time = moment(string.value, "mm:ss");
           var seconds = time.minutes()*60 + time.seconds();
           return seconds;
        }
    }
  },
  rounds: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Rounds"
  }
});
```